# Javascript, pushing object in for loop result in duplicated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a problem to push objects inside another object inside a for loop. It result in having duplicated value. I assume the problem is about `references`:

```
var controllers = ["Patrick","Alain"];
var steval = {"name":null,"prix":{max: 5, min: 3},"comments":null};

var evals = [];
for (index = 0; index < controllers.length; ++index) {
      var name = controllers[index];
      var eval = steval;
      eval.name = name;
      console.log(eval);
      evals.push(eval);
}
console.log(evals);
$("#json").html(JSON.stringify(evals));
```

The result is the following :

`[{"name":"Alain","prix":{"max":5,"min":3},"comments":null},{"name":"Alain","prix":{"max":5,"min":3},"comments":null}]`

What I don't understand is that my `console.log(eval)` return the correct value but apparently `evals.push(eval)`always push the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> always push the same value

Because there is only a single object in your code: `steval`. All you do is change the `name` property of that one object.

If you want to create multiple objects then create the object inside the loop:

```js
var controllers = ["Patrick","Alain"];
    
var evals = [];
for (index = 0; index < controllers.length; ++index) {
      var name = controllers[index];
      var eval = {"name": name,"prix":{max: 5, min: 3},"comments":null};
      evals.push(eval);
}
console.log(evals);
```

---

Slight more compact:

```js
var controllers = ["Patrick","Alain"];
        
var evals = controllers.map(name => {
  return {"name": name,"prix":{max: 5, min: 3},"comments":null};
});

console.log(evals);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that indeed, but it felt it wasn't very pretty do it that way. Is there anyway to "clone" that object instead of simply refering to it ?

Comment: There isn't an easy way if you are working with nested objects. I also don't see any advantage in doing that. "pretty" is relative. E.g. I like it if related code is kept closer together, so I'd prefer to see an object literal where it's needed vs some less clear `clone(someObject)` call where I first have to find out what `someObject` is.

Comment: You're correct indeed that seems more logical

Comment: Storing data separate from logic is a common practice and putting the `steval` inside the method can make it hard to maintain (while the comment above argues it makes it easier to maintain as it's right there).  Also if you happen to want to use it in more than once place, it makes sense to define it in one place.  Depends on scenario / preference, in a small snippet like in the question, it probably *is* easier to put with the code.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Of course, context is everything. We don't know what the data really is, what is dynamic vs static, etc. It's all tradeoffs. Eventually,  a proper `class` might be best solution.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer (credit due), there's only one instance of `steval` which gets changed and pushed.

You can "clone" steval using jquery's [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) (as tagged jquery) with `deep` set to true (as you have nested objects):

```
let eval = $.extend(true, {}, steval);
```

Alternatively, you could JSON stringify/parse to make a clone (or store the original as JSON to skip the stringify part) - but it's not ideal.

```js
var controllers = ["Patrick","Alain"];
var steval = {"name":null,"prix":{max: 5, min: 3},"comments":null};

var evals = [];
for (index = 0; index < controllers.length; index++) {
      var name = controllers[index];
      let eval = $.extend(true, {}, steval);
      eval.name = name;
      console.log(eval);
      evals.push(eval);
}
console.log(evals);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(evals));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```